# Tabela só preenche o titulo das colunas

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Eu escrevi o método abaixo:

```
public void setListaCompra() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM\n" +
                     "(\n" +
                     "    SELECT \n" +
                     "    produtos.id AS id, \n" +
                     "    nome_produto AS Nome, \n" +
                     "    SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque, \n" +
                     "    Periodicidade AS Periodicidade, \n" +
                     "    produtos.estoquemax_produto AS 'Média de venda mensal',\n" +
                     "    IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto * 2, 'Muito alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > produtos.estoquemax_produto , 'Alto', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) *0.5, 'Bom', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) > (produtos.estoquemax_produto / IF(Periodicidade = 'M' , 1 , IF(Periodicidade = 'Q' , 2 , 4))) * 0.3, 'Baixo', IF(SUM(estoque.Estoque_produto) >  0, 'Crítico', 'Zerado'))))) AS 'Nível estoque', \n" +
                     "    precos.Custo_produto AS Custo, \n" +
                     "    produtos.fornecedor_principal AS Fornecedor,\n" +
                     "    Descricao_produto AS 'Marca/Laboratório', \n" +
                     "    grupos_prod.Nome_grupo AS Grupo, \n" +
                     "    subgrupos.Nome AS Subgrupo\n" +
                     "\n" +
                     "    FROM genius.produtos\n" +
                     "    JOIN produtos_estoque AS estoque ON produtos.id = estoque.id_produto\n" +
                     "    JOIN produtos_precos AS precos ON produtos.id = precos.id_produto\n" +
                     "    JOIN subgruposprodutos AS subgrupos ON produtos.Id_grupo = subgrupos.Id\n" +
                     "    JOIN grupos_produtos AS grupos_prod ON subgrupos.id_grupo = grupos_prod.Id\n" +
                     "    GROUP BY Id\n" +
                     ") AS d\n" +
                     "WHERE ?";
        String resultado;
        String pesquisa;
        String estado;
        String campo = null;

        pesquisa = txtPesquisaCompra.getText();
        if (cmbEstado.getSelectedItem().equals("Todos")) {
            estado = "";
        } else {
            estado = cmbEstado.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        if (radFornecedor.isSelected()) {
            campo = "d.Fornecedor";
        } else if (radGrupo.isSelected()){
            campo = "d.Grupo";
        } else if (radMarca.isSelected()){
            campo = "d.`Marca/Laboratório`";
        } else if (radNome.isSelected()){
            campo = "d.Nome";
        }

        resultado = campo + " LIKE '%" + pesquisa +"%' AND d.`Nível estoque` LIKE '%" + estado + "%'";
        System.out.println(resultado);
        try {
            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, resultado);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            tblCompra.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Quando eu executo o método ele preenche só o titulo das colunas e não aparece nenhuma linha, inicialmente achei que o problema era no valor da String resultado, pois ela que é usada para preencher o valor da cláusula WHERE:

```
 pst.setString(1, resultado);
```

então peguei o valor da String usando:

```
System.out.println(resultado);
```

que deu:

```
d.Nome LIKE '%%' AND d.`Nível estoque` LIKE '%%'
```

e fiz direto no MySql, e funcionou perfeitamente me retornando todos os valores, então o problema deve estar na tabela, mas não sei onde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa preparedStatements, os parâmetros devem conter apenas valores, não deve haver uma expressão sql nelas, como vc está fazendo.
Você deve alterar seu algoritmo para ao invés de algo assim:

```
"WHERE ?";
```

Você ter algo assim:

```
"WHERE d.Nome LIKE ? AND d.`Nível estoque` LIKE ?";
```

E aí sim, você informa os parâmetros.

Comment: Eu acabei descobrindo sozinho, mas era isso mesmo, muito obrigado. será que não tem nenhuma forma de usar expressões nos parâmetros ou  algo equivalente? pois o código ficou bem pequeno, mas como não deu o código acabou ficando enorme e lento, e seria uma mão na roda para várias situações

Comment: Veja minha outra resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

vc ainda pode montar a query, por exemplo:
no where vc faz:

```
"WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

e nas condições, vc faz assim:

```
if (radFornecedor.isSelected()) {
    sql += "AND d.Fornecedor LIKE ?";
} else
...
}
```

e no parâmetro:

```
pst.setString(1, "%" + pesquisa + "%");
```

Outra, se vc está preocupado com performance, não concatene Strings, ao invés disso, use um StringBuilder.

Comment: Agora ficou perfeito.